# How do I get Bitmap from a TransitionDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap, classcastexception

I have a TransitionDrawable whose Bitmap I need. When I use `getCurrent()` to get its Drawable, apparently the result is still a `TransitionDrawable`. But the truth is the TransitionDrawable was created in another class using

```
final TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
  new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent), drawable });
```

where `drawable` is a BitmapDrawable. But if I try to cast as

```
Bitmap bmp = (BitmapDrawable) transitionDrawable.getCurrent();
```

then I get a class cast exception.

For context, this is the TransitionDrawable in line 378 of ImageWorker of BitmapFun.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? If yes, please share it.

Answer (score 1):

TransitionDrawable inherits from LayerDrawable so you can use findDrawableByLayerId(int id) to get a specific drawable.

example:  using btn_toggle_bg.xml from android sources (4.4.1)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+android:id/background" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_default_small" />
<item android:id="@+android:id/toggle" android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_toggle" />
</layer-list>
```

and assuming that it is acquired in the transitionDrawable object:

```
Drawable d = transitionDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId( android.R.id.background );
```

The background id is defined by android, so that's why the R is scoped to android.  If you created the id in your own app it would look like `<item android:id="@+id/mylayerid" ...`  and then you would find it with `.findDrawableByLayerId( R.id.mylayerid );`

When you build the Transition drawable in code you will need to assign each drawable .

```
transitionDrawable.setDrawableBylayerId( android.R.id.background, new ColorDrawable(..) );
```

if the id doesn't exist, it will be added as a layer with that id.

hope that helps

Comment: can you provide an example ?